# FB developers, request to migrate between apps

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, data-migration

According to Facebook policies, the use of the FaceBook app with the login functionality we were using has been discontinued.
As a result, when we requested an app inventory to Facebook, the response we received was to create a new app and provide services through it.

However, creating a new app means that we won't be able to access the user data that was used in the previous app.

Is it possible to request the transfer of data from the previous app to the new app from Facebook?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: _"the use of the FaceBook app with the login functionality we were using has been discontinued"_ - what do you mean by that? Are you saying you were using a 3rd-party app not under your control?

Comment: And why can't you keep using that app id now?

Comment: Yes, our company have an app(Login Function Oauth).
This app was stoped by FB Dev. The reason is violate policies.
But If we create another new app, previous users cannot access our service anymore.

Comment: They usually give you an opportunity to fix issues with policy violations, and then get the app enabled again - was that not possible in your case?

Comment: I am guessing https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/id-matching#given-a-user-id-for-an-app--retrieve-the-ids-for-other-apps-owned-by-the-same-business could help - but not sure if that still works for an already disabled app.

Comment: Yes, FB give an opportunity to fix issues with policy violations whitin 100 days.
But My superviser said "We didn't".  

I think our app is completely stop.
So they answered remove the app and recreate new app.